# Resize Controls When Form Resize

Tags: c#, winforms

I just wondering about my windows Application. When i re-size windows form that time my Form controls should re-size. Can any body tell me how to do this I have Used Anchor property for that but no luck.

This is a win form.

Comment: Please show us your code. What do you mean with "No luck with anchor property"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there are two ways to make a control automatically resize based on size changes of the :

1. Set the Dock property of the control to [DockStyle.Fill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock.aspx).
2. Set the [Anchor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171691.aspx) property to "Top, Bottom, Left, Right"

But if you decide to use WPF [GridLayout](http://wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html),it has a lot Capability for this target.

**Edited**

See this short tutorial [Resizing controls with form: Anchor property Tutorial](http://www.tutorialized.com/view/tutorial/C-Resizing-controls-with-form-Anchor-property/52689)

Comment: @Ramdas Bhosale:see my link also

Answer (score 4):

You have to use  the **anchor** property in properly.
For example, for DataGridview to resize in its all direction, you have to set its anchor property as **Top, Bottom, Left, Right**

You have to set the anchor property suitably for each controls in the form as per your requirement.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the `Dock` property of your `control` to `Fill`. You could also take a look at the `tableLayoutPanel` if you have more controls which you want to keep aligned while resizing your form.