# Resize User Control in Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a program that uses user controls to change pages, all the controls remain in *one window*

The problem is, the different pages need different sizes, example, here is my user control interface :

[image: IMG1]

Here's  that in runtime:

[image: IMG2]

As you can see the items stay in the corner, as i understand the usercontrol goes on the main form, how do i get it so that the first "Authenticator" page will be in a small box and then after it logs in it will resize to another declared size

Please ask for more information if needed
-Thanks!

Comment: This explains how to anchor your controls: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8y52cxte(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You could add this.ClientSize = someControl.Size; but that is certainly not how UI behaves that you ever used before.  A wildly jumping window is very distracting to a user.  Maybe one size does not fit all, a login dialog is traditionally shown as a dialog.  Sketching out your UI and discussing the design with team members and client before you start programming is *highly* advisable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resize Controls When Form Resize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15942682/resize-controls-when-form-resize)

Comment: @HansPassant Now that you mentioned it, you are right,  i decided to change the login to a  proper dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting a `Control.MaximumSize`for the control. You can use the `Control.Anchor` property to align it in the parent form/control.